# Authentication in Next.js (App Router) and External Express API with Express-Session

Tags: express, rest, next.js, session-cookies, next-auth

I'm trying to develop an application using Next.js but I have an external API using Express.js and express-session. When the user logs in using the login form on Next.js (App Router), I validate it on express.js and then return a token in a cookie as a response. I couldn't find a detailed document on how I can apply this to Next.js and create protected and public routes.